# How do I publish a web project (ASP.net) to my PC's IIs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I'm running Windows 7, and I already have IIs installed. But when I try to publish my project through visual studio's (-visual web developer's) web deploy – though it tells me it succeeded – either I don't know how to see it in a browser, or I'm putting wrong data into the dialog. What I put in is:

1. Service url – "localhost"
2. Site/application – "default web site/mysite"

But then when I open my browser and type in "mysite" or even "default web site/mysite" the browser doesn't find it.

When I set the prpperties->web to "use visual studio development server" and hit f5 it works. But when I set it to "use local IIS web server" – it doesn't.

I've searched for a solution but have found none.

So how *is* it done?

EDIT: when I enter "localhost/mysite" in my browser I get a very long error. "Server Error in '/WebApplication1' Application. Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version......."

Comment: Check to see if a virtual directory was created on the target machine?

Comment: @IrishChieftain Thanks for your reply. I clicked on "create virtual directory" and it told me that "the virtual directory was created successfully". How do I actually check that? "Where" should I check?

Comment: Does the site render now? Try a browser refresh? Also check the default document exists in IIS

Comment: @IrishChieftain The default document exists (assuming I'm checking correctly – I clicked on content view in iis). Also, I meant that I already created the virtual directory before that. Anyway, a refresh didn't help. Anything else?

Comment: Click the document icon in IIS (version?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015129

To resolve this issue, run the following command line:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe /iru
```

The Aspnet_regiis.exe file can be found in one of the following locations:

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 (on a 64-bit computer)

More information here:

http://devonenote.com/2010/06/could-not-load-type-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule/

Comment: Hm, the docs say `-iru`, as opposed to `/iru`, perhaps it works with both?